# WP7 3 tier architecture unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, azure

I have a WP7 application that uses a 3 tier architecture with an Azure service in the middle carrying out all DB manipulations but have run into difficulty when trying to wrote unit tests for this.

Can anybody suggest any methods on how I could test my system

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Usual unit test solutions will work fine in this scenario. On the Windows Phone side, you can create a mocking service. That is, you don’t actually connect to Windows Azure, but you have an interface that is identical to the Windows Azure service interface. This interface returns some mocked data. You test against this mocked interface. On the Windows Azure side, you need to do some unit tests on data accessing layer as well as the service layer. I assume you use Entity Framework, you can create a unit test to test the CRUD operations without introducing the service. As for the service layer, you need to add a service reference in another unit test (suppose you’re using SOAP or OData), and then do the test.